# cursor won't change in edittext

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-edittext

So I have an EditText, (two actually, but both have the same problem,) and I added an OnTouchListener.  I need to know what EditText I'm working with for another method.  The problem is, before adding the listener, if I clicked somewhere in the EditText, the cursor would update.  Now the cursor won't update at all.

```
 editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            et.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does the issue still occur if you set the return value to `false`?

Comment: Yes, that works.  For some reason it was causing a weird runtime error when false before.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it. I've written up an answer with more information on why it makes more sense for the return value to be `false` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is best to return `false` in `onTouch`. This is because the [return value specifies whether or not the listener consumes the event.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent)) Returning false should therefore allow the widget to respond to the touch event with its normal behaviour, in addition to whatever else you have specified.